# Treat null as 0 for generic types

Tags: c#, generics

Want to convert generic typed null values to "0." I wrote the following to try to temporary convert back and forth after setting, but get an exception when value is null...

```
IEvaluateService Create<T>(
            string compareOperator,
            T value,
            ...)
{
    value ??= (T)Convert.ChangeType("0", typeof(T));
}
```

Exception: `System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32,`

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] that we can try out? I'm not entirely sure what you expected the code to actually do, other than that it currently doesn't do it, whatever it is.

Comment: Nothing you do will **EVER** let you assign the number `0` to a string variable. The best you can hope for is a string with the character `"0"`. Additionally, nothing you do will **EVER** let you assign the string `"0"` to an integer variable. The best you can hope for is the number `0`. Rest assured, those are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are after the [default literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)

```
value = default;
```

That will convert to null for reference types, or whatever the [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) is for value types. I.e. 0 for numeric types and false for booleans.

But combining it with the [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) probably makes little sense since a value type cannot be null, so assigning the default value would never happen for value types, and default would be null for reference types, so it seem to always be a no-op. So you should probably think about what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

If you want to represent non existing values in generic methods I would suggest a [Maybe/Option type](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1510/maybe-monad-csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do:

```
            T value,
//...
{
    var u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
    if (u != null)
    {
        value ??= (T)Convert.ChangeType(0, u);
    }
}
```

I write `0`, not `"0"`.